# Browser detection and addClass

Tags: jquery, browser, addclass

This doesn't work

```
if( $.browser.opera ){
    $("body").addClass('opera');
}
```

why?

Comment: what does not work? It gives an error? The code inside the if doesn't get executed?

Comment: The code works for me well. Are you sure you have properly included jQuery? What errors are you getting?

Comment: No error in opera, code inside if statement executed!

Comment: I'm using 2 jquery with jQuery.noConflict(true). One is jquery 1.3 which is connected on jq13 variable, another is jquery 1.2.

Comment: Does other parts of the JQuery library work?

Comment: How about you post some code, someone might be able to help you

Comment: Other jQuery codes, library's work's perfectly. c0mrade, other part's work's fine. only this part doesn't work. if statement is true, alert('') inside if statement executed.

Comment: did you put in inside document ready ? or window.onload = init; where init is the function which assigns class to your body in case of opera browser

Comment: yes I have put this into jQuery document ready.

Comment: hmmm strange. this work's for firefox
if( $.browser.mozilla ) {
        $('body').addClass('mozilla');
    }

Comment: Maybe error's in other part of javascript code? I know firefox ignores that errors, but opera doesn't give any error.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that code above, if there was error firebug would tell you about the existence of errors if any

Comment: firebug doesn't give any error...

Comment: Then problem in opera. But what's the problem? Maybe bug? :D

Comment: Have you tried to executed this in $(window).load function instead of document ready ? Does opera class work if you assign it to body by default directly without any javascript ?

Comment: its not a bug it works fine for me..

Comment: here is my body in opera, I have added 'opera' manually from HTML. it's ok. <body class="not-front not-logged-in no-sidebars page-news section-news opera">

Comment: hmm .. try this then $("body").attr("class", "not-front not-logged-in no-sidebars page-news section-news opera");

Comment: nothing :( doesn't work.

Comment: well I think this is beyond mine and anyone else ability to help unless you show us some code..

Comment: Here is my custom jquery code: http://pastebin.com/f43c5ff7f

Comment: why add html class instead of body, how about you create div id="anything" .. then try to apply the addClass to the #anything div .. just to see if that will be working .. either addClass or attr()

Comment: if you strictly need to add class to your html here is the link http://snipplr.com/view/14992/add-hasjs-class-to-html-element/

Comment: doesn't work on div element :( maybe the problem in jquery noConflict mode? first i'm including jquery 1.3, after it after it's i'm connecting jquery 1.3 to jq13 variable with this code var jq13 = jQuery.noConflict(true); after it goes jquery 1.2 include. But I have no problem with other libraries...

Comment: I detect that some jquery plugins doesn't work in opera. only in opera. What can you suggest for debugging in opera?

Comment: Add this $.noConflict(); before your code without var jq13 .. or read http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ .. or why not just use the latest jquery

Comment: I found problem :))
this part is calling problems. "  var myBorder = RUZEE.ShadedBorder.create({ shadow:16 });
  myBorder.render('page');" this adds shadow left and right sides of page. Sorry. And many many thanks for helping :)))

Comment: I'm using different versions of jquery because some plugins is not jquery 1.3 compatible.

Comment: no problem, you should then answer your own question so people know when they come about the same problem

Comment: hehe, the problem is not the myBorder... it is another problem. There is no problem using addClass. When opera loads there is no opera in body in sourcecode, but when I add in CSS body.opera{display:none;} it's executed. So problem is was in browser. Browser doesn't make jquery changes in sourcecode of browser. :))

Comment: something tells me this is wrong: 27 comments and 2 answers...

Comment: What wrong? You want to say that c0mrade it's me? :)) Welcome administration :) check me :)

Comment: @Toktik naaa let him go .. instead of focusing on help he is rather trying to prove something, whatever .. anyways you should accept your answer as solution its been a while now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem using addClass. When opera loads there is no 'opera' class in body when I view sourcecode, but when I add in CSS body.opera{display:none;} it's executed. So problem is in browser. Browser doesn't make jQuery changes in user visible source code of browser.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
if( $.browser.opera ){
    $("body").attr("class", "opera");
}
```